# How to add different rules for specific files?

Tags: makefile

I have a certain problem with my Makefile.

With this command, I can compile all my *.c files to *.o which works well:

```
$(OBJ) : %.o : %.c $(LDSCRIPT) Makefile
    $(CC) $(ARM9_INCLUDES) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

But now I'm wondering, what if I want to run `-O3` optimization on just ONE particular file, and have `-O0` on the rest?

Is there any command to add a different rule for a specific file?

What I'm doing right now is compiling each C file with its own rules, which is very annoying because I have around 30 files which makes the Makefile *huge*, and every time I change something in one file it compiles EVERYTHING again.

Comment: If you have explicit rule for one file, you can still have pattern rule that will be used for the rest.

Comment: You do know about the `target-list : target-pattern : source-pattern` type rules and didn't think about excluding that one target from the `target-list` and using that pattern rule for the rest?

Comment: This is the first time I work with Makefiles and I kind of copied the Makefile without fully understanding all the mechanics behind it ;/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
particular_file.o : CFLAGS+=-O3
```

(assuming GNU make) see [target-specific variable values](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific) in GNU Make manual
(and the immediately following pattern-specific variable values, maybe).

Also note, that commands are used from the most specific rule for given file, so you can have in case target-specific variable value is not sufficient:

```
particular_file.o : particular_file.c
        completely_special_compiler -o $@ $<

%.o : %.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to make the solution a bit more extensible.

Suppose you need to compile one set of files in one way and the other set of files in another way, rather than having only one exception, and you could identify patterns in those two sets of files, e.g. one set starts with "a", and the other set starts with "b", you can do something like this:

```
a%.o : a%.c
    completely_special_compiler -o $@ $<

b%.o : b%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

For more explanation, see [Static Patterns](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern).